# How do I insert a new object into object and unwrap this new object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object like this

datt.js file:

```
const datt = {
  sub: {
    first: 'Jhon',
    last: 'Doe',
  }
}
```

dott.js file:

```
const dott = {
  company: 'wfh',
  fax: '0000',
};

module.exports = dott;
```

so I'm gonna import this dott file to datt file, what I expected is like this

```
console.log(datt)
/*
   sub: {
    first: 'Jhon',
    last: 'Doe',
    company: 'wfh',
    fax: '0000',
   }
*/
```

and I use this code

```
const dott = require('./dott.js');
const datt = {
  sub: {
    first: 'Jhon',
    last: 'Doe',
    dott,
  }
}
```

but I got like this:

```
/*
   sub: {
    first: 'Jhon',
    last: 'Doe',
    dott: {
      company: 'wfh',
      fax: '0000',
    }
   }
*/
```

this is just a small example, and the data what I want to import is more than 1 file.
Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
first: 'Jhon',
last: 'Doe',
dott,
...
```

This syntax shortcut means to append a new property named dott with value dott (the object), which is a dictionary.

You should use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
{ ...dott }
```

Comment: thank you, i forgot t o use it, it's solved now